# Fluent nHibernate Automapping not creating Plural table name

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, automapping

I have two tables, Locations and Facilities

They map to two classes,

```
public Location : Entity
{
   //properties
}

public Facility : Entity
{
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
}
```

Everything works just dandy, until I change facility to this

```
public Facility : Location
{

}
```

Now I get an exception from nHibernate saying

```
NHibernate.ADOException was unhandled by user code
  Message=could not execute query
 InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
       Message=Invalid object name 'Facility'.
```

For some reason it is not creating the plural name of the table into the sql string.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT

This is my current TableNameConvention

```
public class TableNameConvention : IClassConvention
{
    public void Apply(FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Instances.IClassInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Table(Inflector.Net.Inflector.Pluralize(instance.EntityType.Name));
    }
}
```

When Facility inherits from Entity, the Facility does run through this method.  When it inherits from Location, it does not

Edit 2
Figured I'd post everything...
[image: Database diagram]

```
public class AutoPersistenceModelGenerator : IAutoPersistenceModelGenerator
{

    #region IAutoPersistenceModelGenerator Members

    public AutoPersistenceModel Generate()
    {
        var mappings = new AutoPersistenceModel();
        mappings.AddEntityAssembly(typeof(Person).Assembly).Where(GetAutoMappingFilter);
        mappings.Conventions.Setup(GetConventions());
        mappings.Setup(GetSetup());
        mappings.IgnoreBase<Entity>();
        mappings.IgnoreBase(typeof(EntityWithTypedId<>));
        mappings.UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<AutoPersistenceModelGenerator>();

        return mappings;

    }

    #endregion

    private Action<AutoMappingExpressions> GetSetup()
    {
        return c =>
        {
            c.FindIdentity = type => type.Name == "Id";
        };
    }

    private Action<IConventionFinder> GetConventions()
    {
        return c =>
        {
            c.Add<BHP.DEC.Data.NHibernateMaps.Conventions.ForeignKeyConvention>();
            c.Add<BHP.DEC.Data.NHibernateMaps.Conventions.HasManyConvention>();
            c.Add<BHP.DEC.Data.NHibernateMaps.Conventions.HasManyToManyConvention>();
            c.Add<BHP.DEC.Data.NHibernateMaps.Conventions.ManyToManyTableNameConvention>();
            c.Add<BHP.DEC.Data.NHibernateMaps.Conventions.PrimaryKeyConvention>();
            c.Add<BHP.DEC.Data.NHibernateMaps.Conventions.ReferenceConvention>();
            c.Add<BHP.DEC.Data.NHibernateMaps.Conventions.TableNameConvention>();
        };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides a filter for only including types which inherit from the IEntityWithTypedId interface.
    /// </summary>

    private bool GetAutoMappingFilter(Type t)
    {
        return t.GetInterfaces().Any(x =>
                                        x.IsGenericType &&
                                        x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEntityWithTypedId<>));
    }
}
```

Comment: Fluent NHibernate doesn't do any pluralization of table names, or anything else for that matter. You need to create a convention like David suggested and utilise one of the .Net inflectors out there.

Comment: The tableNameConvention is in there, but for some reason when I change Facility to inherit from Location, the fluent setup no longer finds it when it scans the assembly.

Comment: As-is, it looks like you're treating Location as another base class, in which case the following might work:
mappings.IgnoreBase<Location>();
Or are going for something like a table-per-subclass?

Comment: I'm trying to do table-per-subclass.  There are many properties in Location that I need to reference

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you set a [convention](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Conventions)?

```
public class TableNameConvention : IClassConvention
{
    public void Apply(FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Instances.IClassInstance instance)
    {
        string typeName = instance.EntityType.Name;

        instance.Table(Inflector.Net.Inflector.Pluralize(typeName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah thats in there.  For some reason when I change the Facility to inherit from location Facility does not show up to be added in this table name convention.

Comment: Euh, interesting.  So are you using an inheritance strategy? - http://jagregory.com/writings/fluent-nhibernate-auto-mapping-and-base-classes/

Comment: Yep.  It looks just like the one in the example.  Here is a link: http://yfrog.com/1gdhfp

Comment: I'd appreciate if you could specify to which assembly `Inflector.Net.Inflector.Pluralize` belongs?

Comment: It's an assembly called Inflector.Net. Looks like that's been moving around lately. http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2011/03/15/inflector-for-net.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but for the sake of others who stumble upon this looking for an answer, you can also create a convention that uses the built-in PluralizationService that comes with EF:

```
public class TableNameConvention : IClassConvention
{
    public void Apply(IClassInstance instance)
    {
        string typeName = instance.EntityType.Name;
        instance.Table(PluralizationService.CreateService(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Pluralize(typeName));

    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting mix of nhibernate and EF. We were not allowed to use EF for this project years ago.